# Unable to pass delegate object to another class (Modal View) via IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, storyboard, protocols

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` on my `UINavigationBar` named `selectRoleButton`. Within this class (`AEFeedsViewController`) I have a protocol:

```
@protocol AERoleSelectProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)presentLoginViewController;

@end
```

The `selectRoleButton` is hooked up to `AERoleSelectViewController` by a target action `IBAction`, which holds a `container` that contains `AERoleSelectTableViewController`.

Here is a picture of my Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

Below is the `IBAction` for `selectRoleButton`:

```
- (IBAction)selectRole:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender); // Unable to breakpoint, NSLog won't log...?

    AERoleSelectTableViewController *roleViewControler = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RoleTableVC"];
    roleViewControler.delegate = self; // delegate is not being passed/set

    [self presentViewController:roleViewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So when tapping the button, it presents `AERoleSelectViewController`, with `AERoleSelectTableViewController` in a container. `AERoleSelectTableViewController` has a delegate property of

> `AERoleSelectTableViewController.h
>   @property (weak, nonatomic) id <AERoleSelectProtocol> delegate;`

The IBAction should be passing and setting the `delegate` object, but it is `nil`.  Breakpoints do not seem to work, it won't break at all on the method. I've even tried writing my own method and wiring the button to that, but the breakpoint still won't catch it. I also cannot print anything using `NSLog` method for some reason.

In `AERoleSelectTableViewController.m`, my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` has a switch statement, one case uses the delegate and calls a method on `AEFeedsViewController` which conforms to the `AERoleSelectProtocol`.

```
AERoleSelectTableViewController.m
...  
if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate presentLoginViewController];
}
```

But since the `delegate` is `nil`, it obviously never gets called.

**Edit:**

I have tried disabling the target action `IBAction` on the `selectRole` button and using a segue to present it modally.

[image: selectRole button modal segue]

My segue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showRoleView"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Sender: %@", sender);

        AERoleSelectTableViewController *roleViewController = (AERoleSelectTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        roleViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

The method is being called, I can breakpoint and it is crashing on

> `roleViewController.delegate = self;`

With the crash log:

> [AERoleSelectViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

As mentioned above, I have a `delegate` property on `AERoleSelectTableViewController.h` so it should be passing no problem. But it crashes instantly, `viewDidLoad` doesn't even get called on `AERoleSelectTableViewController`.

Is this something to do with how I'm setting it on a class within a `container`? I tried setting the delegate on the container class (`AERoleSelectTableViewController`) on `[segue destinationViewController]` and when `viewDidLoad` gets called, the delegate object is set, but only the container view is displayed (the just the tableView, no background etc, `RoleSelectViewController` doesn't present at all, which is expected given this code.

When setting the`[segue destinationViewController]` to the class which holds the container (RoleSelectViewController), the containers' class `viewDidLoad` is called first. So the delegate is not set. Then `viewDidLoad` gets called on the class holding the container, with the delegate set successfully. Am I able to pass the delegate from the class which holds the container, to the container even though the container gets called first? Is using a container even the correct approach? Is a container needed or can I just put a tableView straight in there?

Comment: Is selectRole a target action for your bar button?

Comment: Why are you creating the controller yourself and calling `presentViewController`? the segues already create the controllers and present them; instead, why don't you set the delegate in `preapreForSegue`?

Comment: I have tried adding a segue to `roleSelectButton`, and in the `prepareForSegue` method it crashed with `[AERoleSelectViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I will updated my post with the `prepareForSegue` method.
@vishnuvarthan Yes, `selectRole` is a target action for the bar button item.

Comment: Why not print the value of `[segue destinationViewController]` and see whether the object belongs to the class you expect?